# Updating one to many relation in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities `Node` and `Relation`, where `Relation` have a one-to-many attribute `child` and a one-to-many attribute `parent` which are both linked to a `Node` entity.

Initially, I only had the `parent` attribute reversed in the `Node` entity by a `childs` attribute and everything worked both on my test and on my production environment.

Then I decided to add the `parents` attribute to `Node` to inverse the `child` attribute of `Relation` and it worked without any issue on my test environment, even on the data registered before the change.

Here is the relevant code for both entities :

```
class Relation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Node::class, inversedBy="childs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Node::class, inversedBy="parents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $child;

    public function __construct(Node $parent, Node $child)
    {
        $this->setChild($child);
        $parent->addChild($this);
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getParent(): ?Node
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent(?Node $parent): self
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getChild(): ?Node
    {
        return $this->child;
    }

    public function setChild(?Node $child): self
    {
        $this->child = $child;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
class Node
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Relation::class, mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $childs;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Relation::class, mappedBy="child")
     */
    private $parents;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->childs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Relation[]
     */
    public function getParents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->parents;
    }

    public function addParent(Relation $relation): self
    {
        if (!$this->parents->contains($relation)) {
            $this->parents->add($relation);
            $relation->setChild($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeParent(Relation $relation): self
    {
        if ($this->parents->removeElement($relation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($relation->getChild() === $this) {
                $relation->setChild(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Relation[]
     */
    public function getChilds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->childs;
    }

    public function addChild(Relation $relation): self
    {
        if (!$this->childs->contains($relation)) {
            $this->childs->add($relation);
            $relation->setParent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeChild(Relation $relation): self
    {
        if ($this->childs->removeElement($relation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($relation->getParent() === $this) {
                $relation->setParent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, on the production server, `getParent()` returns `null` - and not even an empty `ArrayCollection` and I have the following error showing up in the logs : `CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Return value of Node::getParents() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, null returned`.

I don't find any difference between the database structure on the production and on my test, I don't have access to the shell on the server and I need to keep the data intact on the server.
I also tried loading the production database on my computer and it worked fine.

Both the server and my test environment run on MariaDB.

I tried forcing the type of `parents` in the declaration using either `private Collection $parents` or `private ArrayCollection $parents` but I got this message in the logs : `CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Typed property Node::$parents must not be accessed before initialization"`

I belive the answer lies in how ORM/Doctrine loads the entity.

I have tried removing the cache with no change.
I have noticed in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/basic-mapping.html)  that an instance of the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata` class should be cached but I only see instances of `Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy` in the cache folder of Doctrine, I am not quite sure if it is relevant and I don't really know how to explore this lead but I don't have many other ideas of where to look.

Comment: Did you try to use 'php bin/console d:s:v' to validate your doctrine schema? Otherwise, you seems to use PHP7.4, so if collection cannot be null, i suggest you to declare the type in 'private $parents;' => 'private Collection $parents;'

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't access the shell of the server so I can't run `php bin/console d:s:v`...

So I just tried to set `private ArrayCollection $parent` and I got this error in the logs :
`CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Typed property Node::$parents must not be accessed before initialization"`

Comment: What kind of situation do you have this problem? Is it just retrieved from doctrine? From a symfony form?

Comment: No form involved the `Relation` and `Node` entities are represented in the database and the `relation` table has `child` and `parent` attributes and Doctrine automatically hydrates the `Node->$childs` attribute but not the `Node->$parent` one. So I presume there is something I am missing but I don't now where to look for it.

Comment: Well, force the type to collection by declaring private Collection $parents;. It should fail way before you call the getter if it is still null

Comment: If I force the type to `Collection` it fails as soon as I try to access the property because it is not initialized, which makes sense because the type is only checked by PHP when the property is accessed and Doctrine would have initialized it even without the type if it was taking charge of this property.